# -bash: chmod +x: command not found . Using the chmod +x command on MacOS gives error

Tags: macos, chmod

On my MAC, I'm typing in the chmod +x command, and getting the following error -

```
-bash: chmod +x: command not found
```

What should be done here?

echo $PATH

```
/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.4
```

Comment: Could be an issue with `PATH`. Could you update your question with the output of `echo $PATH`? I don't have a Mac to confirm it on at the moment, but on Linux `chmod` is located at `/usr/bin/chmod`

Comment: done the same..

Comment: Seems like you've overwritten (as opposed to appended) the `PATH` variable, so that explains it. If you've done it manually in the current shell, just start a new shell, but if you have set it in a config file (e.g., `.zshrc`), revert the change and restart the shell.

Comment: My bash profile looks like -

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed that you were using `zsh` since you're on macOS, hehe, but I see now that it's bash, so replace `.zshrc` with any of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` for per-user config (since it seems like you're running a login shell).

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I don't really follow what your `~/.bash_profile` looks like and you haven't told us whether you're modifying the `PATH` environment variable in any shell startup script or if you only set it manually in the current shell. See my second comment of this thread.

Comment: changed the path variable to /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/apache-maven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to use terminal commands normally, your $PATH value should be something like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

If you want to keep `/Applications/apache-maven-3.8.4` as $PATH for some reason
, then you should use

```
/bin/chmod +x /Users/someone/Documents/some_file
```

instead of

```
chmod +x /Users/someone/Documents/some_file
```

**Edit:**

The error message included the +x as part of the name of the command that wasn't found

I figured out, that you can recreate the error by entering this command in the terminal: `"chmod +x" test.txt`
--> `zsh: command not found: chmod +x` To fix it you should do `"chmod" +x test.txt`.

Comment: The error message included the `+x` as part of the name of the command that wasn't found. That implies a different error than the one you're describing how to fix here. (It should be `bash: chmod: command not found`, not `bash: chmod +x: command not found`)

Comment: I figured out, that you can recreate the error by entering this command in the terminal: "chmod +x" test.txt 

--> zsh: command not found: chmod +x 

to fix it you should do "chmod" +x test.txt